# Cannot Pass Tuples into List View

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui, tuples, swiftui-list

I have an app whose UI was built with StoryBoard, that I'm now trying to convert to SwiftUI. The problem I'm having is that the app consists largely of arrays of Tuple data that is passed through Tableviews. In SwiftUI, however, I can't find a way to pass tuple data into the list view. I keep getting the following error message:

> Type '(String, String, String)' cannot conform to 'Hashable'; only
> struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols.

I tried passing my tuple arrays through structs to see if I could get it to work that way, but was unable to effectively decode the tuple arrays through the structs. Anyone have any ideas? My code presently is as follows:

```
struct Result: View {
    
    let tupleArray = [("a", "z", "c"), ("e", "x", "d"), ("c", "y", "x")]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.tupleArray, id: \.self) { item in
                    ResultsRowView(text0: item.0, text1: item.1, text2: item.2)
                }
            }//:LOOP
        }
    }
}
```

My List Row View is as follows:

```
struct ResultsRowView: View {
    
    var text0 = "a"
    var text1 = "b"
    var text2 = "c"
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text(text0)
            Text(text1)
            Text(text2)
        } //:HSTACK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift tuples can't conform to `Hashable` - see [How do I make (Int,Int) Hashable?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/109146)

And the error you get says exactly that:

> only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols.

A possible solution is to create a custom struct conforming to `Hashable`:

```
struct Model: Hashable {
    let item1: String
    let item2: String
    let item3: String
}
```

and use it like this:

```
struct Result: View {
    let tupleArray = [("a", "z", "c"), ("e", "x", "d"), ("c", "y", "x")]
        .map(Model.init)

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.tupleArray, id: \.self) { item in
                    ResultsRowView(text0: item.item1, text1: item.item2, text2: item.item3)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you can use `.map(Model.init)` to easily convert an array of tuples to an array of Model objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
ForEach(tupleArray.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    let item = tupleArray[index]
    ResultsRowView(text0: item.0, text1: item.1, text2: item.2)
}
```

Alternatively, you could access the array of tuples by index in order to conform to the identifiable requirement.

Comment: Using indices and ranges is considered unsafe with swiftui

Comment: @loremipsum
Do you have an explanation or a source? I will remove my answer if so. I wouldn't usually hard access an array; however, in this case, the access is wrapped safely as far as I can tell. It's similar to accessing data in UIKit with data[indexPath.row].

Comment: The WWDC video Demystify SwiftUI, SwiftUI is all about identity the index isn't a good way to establish identify.

Comment: `id: \.self` is also talked about there